# Firebase v3 transactions and promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling a bit with how to handle transactions in Firebase v3.

I tried the following:

```
function fbTransaction(childRef) {
    var qTrans = Q.defer();

    firebase.database().ref(childRef).transaction()
    .then(function(success){
        qTrans.resolve(success);
    }).catch(function(error){
        qTrans.reject(error);
    });

    return qTrans.promise;
};
```

Thus I try to update the value at the location `childRef`. When I try it as I do then it does not return any promise. Basically nothing happens.

I also tried the example from the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), but that keeps returning null for both `post` and `success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay figured it out. You can basically set an initial value and decrease it with `--`.

```
function fbTransaction(childRef) {
    var qTrans = Q.defer();
    firebase.database().ref(childRef).transaction(function(post) {
        if (post != null) {
            post++;
        } else {
            post = 1;
        }
        return post;
    }).then(function(success){
        qTrans.resolve();
    }).catch(function(error){
        qTrans.reject(error);
    });
    return qTrans.promise;
};
```